# Is it possible to intersect two lattices and that their intersection is not a lattice?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, lattice-orders

Draw the line diagram of two lattices whose intersection is not a lattice. I have tried to do it with division, with containment relation, and yet I still cannot solve this exercise, I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

$ L_1 = \{1, 2, 3, 6\} $, $L_2 = \{1, 2, 3, 12\}$, where the ordering is 'divides into.'